# how to parametrise the variable in the abstract class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the below abstract class where character_1, character_2, character_3 are decleared.

```
public abstract class Properties {
 public static final String character_1 = "//*[@class='character- nav-slide-normal'][@alt='CHARLIE E LOLA']";
 public static final String character_2 = "//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='PEPPA']";
 public static final String character_3 = "//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='FESTA HI-5']";
}
```

How can I parameterise that and passing through to properties.

```
String[] myStringArray = {"character_1","character_2","character_3"};
    for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++)
    {
      String value = myStringArray[i];
        String altvalue =   driver.findElement(By.xpath(Properties.value)).getAttribute("alt");
        System.out.print(altvalue);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me, but I think your trying to use the field names as String? In that case you probably should use something like a `HashMap<String, String>`

Comment: I need how to send the value (i.e myStringArray[i] ) to Properties. ???????? so that when i = 0,  String altvalue =   driver.findElement(By.xpath(Properties.character_1)).getAttribute("alt"); when i=1 , String altvalue =   driver.findElement(By.xpath(Properties.character_2)).getAttribute("alt");  like that. Hope the question is clear now.

Comment: The purpose of abstract method is completely different.. It you need to parameter the value of the xpath then we can use collections such as list or map...

Comment: its not the value of the xpath i need to parameter. I need that variable to be parametrised. That variable in the abstract class can contain either xpath, css selector or id etc. That abstract class is the only place which I use that contains around 100 these kind of indicators and we call it in the method as By.xpath or By.id or By.cssSelector etc....

Answer (score 0):

You could use an enum. Something along the lines of

```
public enum Properties {

CHARACTER_1("//*[@class='character- nav-slide-normal'][@alt='CHARLIE E LOLA']"),
CHARACTER_2("//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='PEPPA']"),
CHARACTER_3("//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='FESTA HI-5']"),
CHARACTER_4("//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='FESTA HI-5']"),
CHARACTER_5("//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='FESTA HI-5']"),
CHARACTER_6("//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='FESTA HI-5']"),
CHARACTER_7("//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='FESTA HI-5']");

private String xpath;

Properties(String xpath) {
    this.xpath = xpath;
}

public String getXpath() {
    return xpath;
}
```

}

Example

```
// Selective properties 
    Properties[] selectiveProperties = {Properties.CHARACTER_1, Properties.CHARACTER_3, Properties.CHARACTER_6, Properties.CHARACTER_7};

    for (Properties property : selectiveProperties) {
        String altvalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(property.getXpath())).getAttribute("alt");
        System.out.print(altvalue);
    }


    //Iterate through all the properties 
    for (Properties property : Properties.values()) {
        String altvalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(property.getXpath())).getAttribute("alt");
        System.out.print(altvalue);
    }
```

Comment: I want to keep the Properties as an abstract class. I need the easiest way to do something so that  that when i = 0, String altvalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Properties.character_1)).getAttr‌​ibute("alt"); when i=1 , String altvalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Properties.character_2)).getAttr‌​ibute("alt"); like that.

Comment: I don't see why there is any need to have Properties as an abstract class if it just contains a list of 100 static final strings. Is there any particular reason you want to keep it abstract?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest is to use a `HashMap<String, String>`.

```
public class Properties { //no particular use to make this class abstract
    public static final Map<String, String> characters;
    static
    {
        characters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        characters.put("character_1", "//*[@class='character- nav-slide-normal'][@alt='CHARLIE E LOLA']");
        characters.put("character_2", "//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='PEPPA']");
        characters.put("character_3", "//*[@class='character-nav-slide-normal'][@alt='FESTA HI-5']");
    }
}

//somewhere else...
String[] myStringArray = {"character_1","character_2","character_3"};
for (String stringArrayString : myStringArray)
{
    String xPath = Properties.characters.get(stringArrayString);
    String altvalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).getAttribute("alt");
    System.out.print(altvalue);
}
```

You can easily use above code to solve your problem.

However, your quote indicates that you already have something in mind:

> I need how to send the value (i.e myStringArray[i] ) to Properties.
>   ???????? so that when i = 0, String altvalue =
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath(Properties.character_1)).getAttr‌​ibute("alt");
>   when i=1 , String altvalue =
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath(Properties.character_2)).getAttr‌​ibute("alt");
>   like that.

While it is possible with reflection, it is heavily discouraged: you lose compile-time type safety, it causes bugs when refactoring, and performance is slower.